# jqueryUI Css widget, how to prevent descendant

Tags: css, jquery-ui, class, descendant

i'd like to prevent CSS from my styles do descendants of descendants without giving them classes or ids? my jQueryUI widget are affected by my ascendant CSS.
i've tried
For instance: 
`.myClass > ul {...} instead of .myClass ul {...}`
but it doesn't work (checked with Firebug 1.5/FF 3.6)
.myClass MUST BE a class, not an id (#). It seems to work with id, but that's not what i want..
In fact, i'd like something to 'contain' CSS jQueryUI Widget. 
Thanks from your help.

Comment: Post some code - or better still set it up on jsFiddle

Answer (score 0):

Sebastien

Usually jQueryUI Widgets are wrapped inside a DIV that has a class such as .ui-widget, however those are usually at level of a first child of the body, meaning if you have your layout in something like a #wrapper div, the widgets styles won't be affected be descendant selectors coming from that wrapper, to make things clear:

```
<body>
  <div id="wrapper"><h1>an h1 inside the wrapper</h1></div>
  <div class="ui-widget"><h1>h1 inside the jquery ui widget</h1></div>
</body>
```

So if you do put #wrapper in front of all your styles jQueryUI won't pick them up.